# Tool to redirect sound from output to input

Tags: linux, audio

I am using SoundflowerBed software on my Mac to re-route my system audio as my dummy mic input, so that I can record what is playing on my system audio.

I need a similar software that will work in Linux.

That is: A tool that picks up the output and provides it as input or alternatively a tool that picks up the output and records it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, what Linux Distro do you use? (Debian? Ubuntu? Mint?)

Comment: I edited your question to be more generic and thus attract experts in Linux that don't know SoundflowerBed. If I got it wrong, please [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/17383/edit) your question.

Answer (score 3):

There's a fair few ways of doing this, but the easiest is probably the following:

Install "pavucontrol" and "audacity" from ubuntu software centre or via terminal. (`sudo aptitude install pavucontrol audacity` or `sudo yum install pavucontrol audacity`).

Open up Audacity (from the menu or via a terminal with `audacity`).

Select "pulse*" as recording device in Audacity.

Click Record Button.

Open PulseAudio Volume Control (Search For PulseAudio Volume Control in the menu or dash).

Select Recording Tab.

Now You Should see ALSA plug-in [audacity]. If you do not see ALSA plug-in [audacity], make sure you have clicked Record Button in audacity. You should be running recording in audacity while performing the next step.

Select "Monitor from *".

Now you should be able to record the sound you hear from speaker or headphones.

Comment: I tried your steps but still could not record the sound from the headphone